# Error in building simple calculator logic using when expression in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

This is my code:

```
fun main() {
    // write your code here
    val firstNumber:Long = readLine()!!.toLong()
    val secondNumber:Long = readLine()!!.toLong()
    val operator = readLine()!!
    when (operator) {
        "+" -> println(firstNumber + secondNumber)
        "-" -> println(firstNumber - secondNumber)
        "/" -> if (secondNumber == 0.toLong()) println("Division by 0!") else println(firstNumber / secondNumber)
        "*" -> println(firstNumber * secondNumber)

        else -> println("Unknown operator")
    }
}
```

I think I am doing everything right but still having an error as shown in image.[image]

Please help me to find where I am wrong.

Comment: You should insert the input values on separate lines (eg. `10000` -> press Enter -> `2000` -> press Enter -> `+` -> press Enter). I think that the problem is that you are currently inserting the string `10000 + 2000` on the first line.

Comment: Got it. Problem solved.